# Updating records in a database using the form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view page, i am using form_tag to create a form which will pass a string of ids from a  hidden field to the controller code.

In my controller code, i am looping through an array of ids to update each record containing that id in the Expression table. But the code below does not seem to work.
I would really appreciate it if somebody could give me some suggestion regarding what is wrong with the code below.

```
def update_expression
  @emi_ids_array = params[:emi_ids].split(/,/)
  @sub_id = params[:sub_id]

  @emi_ids_array.each do |emi_id|
    @existing_exp = Expression.find(:first, :conditions => [ "EXT_EMI_ID = ? and EXT_SUB_FK = ?", emi_id, @sub_id])
    @expression = @existing_exp.update_attributes(
      :EXT_SUB_FK => @sub_id,
      :EXT_PRESENCE => "present",
      :EXT_STRENGTH => "weak",
      :EXT_EMI_ID => emi_id
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Just checking but are the params being passed correctly to the function - maybe raise params.inspect to check. Is this Rails 2 or 3? (if 3 maybe change the Expression.find statement to Expression.where).
Is the Expression.find returning any results? Try it in the console with some known params and raise inspect the returned @existing_exp?

Comment: Yes, find method is returning the correct value

Comment: Maybe try the column names in lower-case - not sure how ruby and rails behave with uppercase column names since won't they be considered constants? Think you can work around this be making your own getter and setter methods (very old http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2034) or a variation on Rails 3 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605543/rails-3-easily-work-with-pascal-case-column-names)

Comment: Capitalized column names is highly irregular. Also using the hash-style conditions would simplify this: `{ :ext_emi_id => emi_id, :ext_sub_fk => @sub_id }` The less SQL you can write the less chance of a mistake, I figure.

Comment: I am using a legacy database and all column names are capitalised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a temporary solution. 'update_attributes' does not seem to work, so i opted for 'update_all' attribute

```
 Expression.update_all({:EXT_PRESENCE => "present", :EXT_STRENGTH => "weak"},['EXT_EMI_ID = ? and EXT_SUB_FK = ?', emi_id, @sub_id])
```

Hopefully, it might be useful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the array of ID's (and the sub_id) to integers.

Is it the finding of the object that fails, or the update? Output the `@expression.errors` after the update call to see if there are any validations failing.

Is there a reason for all the instance variables? You don't need the @'s if the variable doesn't go beyond that method. Also the @expression item seems superfluous, you're just duplicating the @existing_exp object, you don't need to put the return into a new object, especially if it's replaced each time the loop runs anyway.

Comment: The ids are in the form EMI:222, so i can;t convert them to integers.

Comment: It is able to find the object. It's only the updating that fails